# LinkedIn API V2 - How to get profile photo used for an organization?

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm using the endpoint https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityAcls?q=roleAssignee&role=ADMINISTRATOR&projection=(elements*(organizationalTarget~(localizedName)))&oauth2_access_token={{access_token}} to get all organizations for a user. I tried different projection fields but still wasn't able to get the profile photo. Is there a way to change projection to get photo or is there possibly another endpoint to get this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I could not figure out a way to get back a logo with the organizationalEntityAcls endpoint. I do not believe its available.

Instead I called the organizations end point with the ids send back from the above.

NOTE: organizationId is just the id not the full URN.

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizations/{organizationId}?projection=(logoV2(original~:playableStreams)),

Answer (score 1):

It is possible actually. This is the call that worked for me.

> https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityAcls?q=roleAssignee&role=ADMINISTRATOR&state=APPROVED&projection=(elements*(organizationalTarget~(id,localizedName,logoV2(original~:playableStreams))))")

Comment: Ironically your call is not working for me (I need to get the logo of a specific organization). It's not returnining the logoV2 field. It works if I call https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizations/18969131?projection=(vanityName)

Comment: Never mind. The organization simply doesn't have a profile picture *facepalm*

Answer (score 0):

Ervin Kalemi's answer is actually right if you want to get photos for all organisations instead of a single organization, but the URL is not fully correct at the end. This URL will work:

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityAcls?q=roleAssignee&role=ADMINISTRATOR&state=APPROVED&projection=(elements*(organizationalTarget~(id,localizedName,logoV2(original~:playableStreams))))

Comment: This does not work.
I get an error "Unsupported URN domain: li:digitalmediaAsset:playableStreams"